# Morgan with Express does not log static files

Tags: express, morgan

Morgan seems to be logging only HTTP requests created using routes like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})
```

I am trying to log requests created using `express.static()`. How do I do that?

Here's my full code:

```
const express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(morgan('tiny'))

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that order matters. Just had to move `morgan` before `express.static()`:

```
app.use(morgan('tiny'))
app.use(express.static('public'));
```